# Comparing the tables and excluding the values

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, where-clause

I have two schemas named as "t3" and "r1". Both have the columns "Permission". Through sql query; I want to Get the list of all permissions from "t3" and excludes the permission from "r1". I am not really into sql that's why it is confusing me a lot.

Comment: You have the _tables_ t3 and r1, I assume.

Comment: Can you show us some sample table data (for t3 and r1), and also the wanted result. (As formatted text, no images.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from t3 
where t3.Permission not in (select Permission from r1)
```

In general, it looks like you need something like that. Although the question is not entirely clear.
This is not the most productive option, if there is a lot of data, you can rewrite it in join and it will be more correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `not exists`: it seems like a straight-forward approach to your querstion; also it usually scales better than `[not] in` when the number of row increases - and it is null-safe (as opposed to `not in`):

```
select t3.permissions
from t3
where not exists (select 1 from r1 where r1.permissions = t3.permissions)
```